# iOS 11 accessing contacts crash

Tags: ios, ios11, contacts, addressbook

We're having issues with iOS-11 users when they try to access contacts in the app, app crashes... but could not ever succeed to reproduce the issue on our side, using devices and simulators.

Application uses AddressBook framework for retrieving the contacts, info.plist also contains all the required privacy descriptions, so we're really stuck.

Comment: how did you detect this crash?

Comment: Without some code/crash report, it's hard to tell what's going on. Please include a [mcve].

Comment: Do you have a stack trace?

Comment: is that a question ?

Comment: i've found out, that the crash happened after the retrieving of contacts but it really didn't make any sense at the time. I was able to find out the source of the problem with iTunesConnect crash log that i never used before. Fairly new to the iOS as you can see. Thanks anyway, sorry for your time everyone.

Comment: @GIJOW since you're in the QUESTIONS section, don't you think that's obvious ?

Comment: @BoštjanKamenik no friend. As can't see any interrogation point nor any code nor anyway to reproduce nor nothing that lead me to believe it is a question

Comment: @GIJOW ok, will improve that in future

Answer (score 0):

We are experiencing the same issue with one of our apps. Some of our users are reporting crashes when searching for contacts in our app, which under the hood we use this cordova plugin: [cordova-plugin-contacts](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts). And well, this plugin uses the [AddressBook](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/addressbook?language=objc) Framework. I found a [post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/86157) in the forums of apple with users talking about it. It seems that the crashing started after iOS 11. And well, AddressBook is deprecated so there is that. The recommended way of accessing contacts should be using the latest API: [CNContactStore](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts/cncontactstore?language=objc). Apple has some [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/contacts?language=objc) on how to use it.

I have some working [code](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-contacts/compare/master...iOffice:updateiosapis?expand=1) myself if you want to look at that.